# "127.0.0.1" option specified, but still using "localhost" name

Tags: mysql

I'm using the -h option, specifying that I want to connect to MySQL Server via a specific host/interface, but MySQL is telling me this, which apparently doesn't make so much sense

```
root@ilg40:/# mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -proot
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

OBS.: I have created a access for root via 127.0.0.1 (FLUSH PRIVILEGES() was already performed.

```
root@ilg40:/# mysql -e "SELECT User,Host,authentication_string FROM mysql.user;"
+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| User      | Host      | authentication_string                     |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| root      | localhost |                                           |
| mysql.sys | localhost | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE |
| root      | 127.0.0.1 | *81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Have you guys any idea about what's going on? 
I can't find where is my failure :(..

P.S: I'm using Debian Jessy + MySQL 5.7.12

```
root@ilg40:/# cat /etc/debian_version 
8.4
root@ilg40:/# mysql -e "SELECT VERSION();"
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.12    |
+-----------+
```

Comment: try this and see if the stored password is the same : SELECT PASSWORD('roor');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acoording to **[MySQL official doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/host-cache.html)**:

> "The server performs host name resolution using the thread-safe
>   gethostbyaddr_r() and gethostbyname_r() calls if the operating system
>   supports them.
>
> Otherwise, the thread performing the lookup locks a mutex
>   and calls gethostbyaddr() and gethostbyname() instead. 
>   In this case, no other thread can resolve host names that are not in the host
>   cache until the thread holding the mutex lock releases it."

The solution I found was: **dropping the user 'root'@'localhost' from MySQL.**

```
DROP USER 'root'@'localhost';
```

I tried to modify the /etc/hosts, but no good. There's something else around the way that MySQL performs these two syscalls, which maps 127.0.0.1 to localhost, independently if you the address mapped in a different way in /etc/hosts.

**WARNING:** be sure to have at least another user with admin powers on MySQL, using 127.0.0.1 for connection, or else, you may loose access and/or admin powers over MySQL.